# How to show the options bar above the Control Panel of joomla

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system

I take over the website in the company

The original company that made the website use Joomla! version 3.9

I want to add a new page at the front office

but the back office doesn't have the option in the Control Panel to let me select modules or install anything

like this:
[It doesn't have System, Users, Extensions ... etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9Qy9.png)

How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure you have a well-asked question yet, but if you are a Joomla user or developer, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask your Joomla questions there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your account has too low privileges.

You should be a Super User, otherwise you will have restrictions in the administration panel.

Only a Super User can create new Super Users.

You can also add a Joomla Super User from phpMyAdmin:
https://www.itoctopus.com/how-to-add-a-joomla-super-user-from-phpmyadmin

Best of luck.

Comment: Hi Johan, if you are a Joomla user or developer, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  We can always use more contributors.

Comment: Ohhhhhh!!!!! You are right!
Thank you very much.